# "Estimator xgboost not available" for PyCaret in google colab?

Tags: python, xgboost, pycaret

Title. For some reason, xgboost isn't showing up as an option for models I can use in pycaret's regression module. I've installed it as needed

[link to colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13F_OuD3JPx_kv6NsGu8gpg8alsFdwFy9?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same issue while working on Google Colab. Instead of doing a normal `pip install pycaret`, do a full install `pip install pycaret[full]`. You can test what all models you have available by running `models()` after you have finished setting up the experiment using `setup()`.

Comment: This also installs catboost, which is not installed otherwise.

Comment: I ma also facing the same issue byt with Catboost.But this lacks many Setup paramters tlike fix_imbalance in classification

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by installing catboost==1.1.1 because pycaret didn't recongize higher versions, it is better that having to install the full version of pycaret if you don't need it.